# Sprintf warnings about formatting

Tags: c, printf, c99

I have a problem regarding `sprintf` formatting in c. No matter which way I format the data, compiler find out another problem. For starters, please consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char text[100];
    uint8_t hours = 1, minutes = 10, seconds = 20;
    int32_t milisec = 300;

    sprintf(text, "[%02u:%02u:%02u.%03i]", hours, minutes, seconds, milisec);
    printf("%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'int32_t {aka long int}' [-Wformat=]
```

If I change the `%u` to `%lu` I get:

```
warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
```

Comment: maybe use the types the compiler you warns about?

Comment: [This `sprintf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be helpful.

Comment: By the way, the warnings you get doesn't match the code you show.

Comment: Please fix the code so that it matches the warnings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a proper [formatting macro](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1) for these types. For example

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t hours = 1, minutes = 10, seconds = 20;
int32_t milisec = 300;

sprintf(text, "[%02" PRIu32 ":%02" PRIu32 ":%02" PRIu32 ".%03" PRId32 "]",
        hours, minutes, seconds, milisec);
```

In the fragment above `PRIu32` is used to print an `uint32_t` in decimal, and `PRId32` to print an `int32_t`.

Another option would be to just use `int/unsigned` for all these values and hope that 32767/65535 hours is enough for everyone.

Comment: I think you should use `PRIu8` for the minutes and seconds, too, to match the declared types in the poster's example.

Answer (score 2):

The header `<inttypes.h>` provides macros such as `PRIu8` and `PRIi32`, which are format string fragments for the standard integer types like `uint8_t` and `int32_t`.  The advantage is that these macros are portable and contain the correct format specifier even if a different fundamental type is used to implement these integer types.